# Streets Missing using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

Does google maps api use an older verison of their maps?  When I embed a map using google maps api, a ton of streets are missing, especially in Israel.

Check this out (this map has lots of detail and streets)
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=israel&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=41.496446,93.076172&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Israel&z=8

Yet the embedded map hee has very little detail on Israel and relatively no streets.
Goto google maps api example page and find israel.  (I couldn't post a link cause this is my first post)

Comment: As of october 5th, 2011, this is not an issue anymore: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/10/grab-bag-of-maps-api-news.html (Map coverage of Israel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a licensing issue. GISrael won't sell Google a universal licence to redistribute the map imagery to other people's domains.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is this is probably a real or perceived security issue for Israel, which makes it an incredible headache for anyone outside of the country to produce a useful map with google map tools. (I've tried to do a map of Jerusalem, a walking tour, and found it nearly impossible to do.)